# get a string and convert it to a variable and assign to a variable in cypress

Tags: cypress

Hi I want to get this value, convert it to a number and assign as a variable. Then I can do calculations. Can someone help on this?

Tried this not working.

```js
const marks = cy.get('.ant-typography \> span').invoke('text').then(parseInt).should('be.gt', 10)

cy.log('The value is '+ marks)
```

.ant-typography > span // this is the locator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.then()` to access the variable

```js
cy.get('.ant-typography > span')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(parseInt)
  .should('be.gt', 10)
  .then(marks => {
    cy.log('The value is '+ marks)
  })
```

---

**Can I return this "marks" value so I can use it outside the `.then()` method?**

See the docs Gleb references, once you have an asynchronous command (even just a `.get()`) you are pretty much stuck with using a `.then()` to access values derived from them.

Even an alias does not help - you need a `.then()` to get it's value.

Comment: Can I return this "marks" value? So I can use it outside the .then method

Comment: See the docs Gleb references, once you have an asynchronous command  (even a `.get()`) you are pretty much stuck with using a `.then()` to access values coming from them.

Comment: Even an alias does not help - you need a `.then()` to get it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about Cypress commands https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-Cypress#Commands-Are-Asynchronous
For your situation specifically, watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aptS3yvqcc

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias to save the value in the variable like this:

```js
cy.get('.ant-typography > span').invoke('text').as('marks')

cy.get('@marks').then((marks) => {
  cy.log('The value is ' + marks) //logs marks
  cy.wrap(+marks).should('be.gt', 10)
})
```